# How to prove the independence of increments of the summation of two independent Poisson processes?

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, poisson-process

Suppose that $\{N_1(t)\,t \ge 0\}$ and $\{N_1(t)\,t \ge 0\}$ are two independent Poisson processes with rates of $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ respectively, then prove the sum process where $N(t) = N_1(t)+N_2(t)$ for all $t \ge 0$ is a Poisson process with rate of $\lambda_1+\lambda_2$.

The proof on my textbook includes the step of proving that $N(t)$ has independent increments, of which the reason is that $N_1(t)$ and $N_2(t)$ are independent and both possess stationary and independent increments properties. But I couldn't understand such an obvious step.

Let $I_1$ and $I_2$ be two disjoint intervals, then our goal is to show that $N_1(I_1)+N_2(I_1)$ and $N_1(I_1)+N_2(I_1)$ are independent. Obviously, we have:

- $N_1(I_1)$, $N_1(I_2)$, $N_2(I_1)$, $N_2(I_1)$ are independent of each other;
- $(N_1(I_1),N_1(I_2))$ and $(N_2(I_1),N_2(I_2))$ are independent random vectors since $\{N_1(t)\,t \ge 0\}$ and $\{N_1(t)\,t \ge 0\}$ are two independent processes.

Next, I only need to prove that $(N_1(I_1),N_2(I_1))$ and $(N_1(I_2),N_2(I_2))$ are two independent vectors to achieve our goal. But I was stuck here. It seems that I'm complicating the question. Does someone have a better idea? Please help me out here.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0J5acxn3y5c

Comment: @JohnDouma Main problem of OP is independence of increments of summation of processes. Not so much the fact that the sum of independent Poissons is again Poisson.

Comment: @drhab Yeah, I’ve updated the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{aligned} & P\left(N_{1}\left(I_{1}\right)+N_{2}\left(I_{1}\right)=r\wedge N_{1}\left(I_{2}\right)+N_{2}\left(I_{2}\right)=s\right)\\
 & =\sum_{r_{1}+r_{2}=r}\sum_{s_{1}+s_{2}=s}P\left(N_{1}\left(I_{1}\right)=r_{1}\wedge N_{2}\left(I_{1}\right)=r_{2}\wedge N_{1}\left(I_{2}\right)=s_{1}\wedge N_{2}\left(I_{2}\right)=s_{2}\right)\\
 & =\sum_{r_{1}+r_{2}=r}\sum_{s_{1}+s_{2}=s}P\left(N_{1}\left(I_{1}\right)=r_{1}\right)P\left(N_{2}\left(I_{1}\right)=r_{2}\right)P\left(N_{1}\left(I_{2}\right)=s_{1}\right)P\left(N_{2}\left(I_{2}\right)=s_{2}\right)\\
 & =\sum_{r_{1}+r_{2}=r}\left[P\left(N_{1}\left(I_{1}\right)=r_{1}\right)P\left(N_{2}\left(I_{1}\right)=r_{2}\right)\sum_{s_{1}+s_{2}=s}P\left(N_{1}\left(I_{2}\right)=s_{1}\right)P\left(N_{2}\left(I_{2}\right)=s_{2}\right)\right]\\
 & =\left[\sum_{s_{1}+s_{2}=s}P\left(N_{1}\left(I_{2}\right)=s_{1}\right)P\left(N_{2}\left(I_{2}\right)=s_{2}\right)\right]\times\left[\sum_{r_{1}+r_{2}=r}P\left(N_{1}\left(I_{1}\right)=r_{1}\right)P\left(N_{2}\left(I_{1}\right)=r_{2}\right)\right]\\
 & =P\left(N_{1}\left(I_{2}\right)+N_{2}\left(I_{2}\right)=s\right)\times P\left(N_{1}\left(I_{1}\right)+N_{2}\left(I_{1}\right)=r\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
showing that $N_{1}\left(I_{1}\right)+N_{2}\left(I_{1}\right)$ and
$N_{1}\left(I_{2}\right)+N_{2}\left(I_{2}\right)$ are independent.

Comment: I guess it’s not as obvious as in the textbook?

Comment: Essential is that the $N_i(I_j)$ are $4$ independent random variables. From that then you can immediately conclude that $N_1(I_1)+N_2(I_1)$ and $N_1(I_2)+N_2(I_2)$ are also independent. In my answer that conclusion is justified.

Comment: Can we extend that to any $n$ independent processes?

Comment: Sure, I don't see why not. You can use induction on $n$ for a proof.

Comment: I was still wondering if $(N_1(I_1),N_2(I_1))$ and $(N_1(I_2),N_2(I_2))$ are two independent vectors. Could you shed more light on it? :)

Comment: Also that is a direct consequence of the fact then $N_1(I_1),N_2(I_1),N_1(I_2,N_2(I_2)$ are independent random variables. Essential is that the processes $N_1,N_2$ are independent and secondly that the intervals $I_1,I_2$ are disjoint.